# Как реализовать функцию "прочитанное/непрочитанное" поле

Tags: mysql

СУТЬ В СЛЕДУЮЩЕМ...
Есть таблица.
Из нее по определенным критериям идет выборка данных по пользовательскому фильтру.

Как бы реализовать функционал, просмотренные/непросмотренные данные
Те что юзер открыл и просмотрел и остальные (непросмотренные)

клиентская часть на JS - все понятно...

А вот как по части БД на сервере...
Править основную таблицу с данными и назначать там просмотр/непросмотр нельзя , ибо данные ОДНИ ДЛЯ ВСЕХ (т.е не как личные сообщения) , а вот фильтра могут быть разные

Т.е надо создавать отдельную таблицу ...

Я думал так , по умолчанию все считать непросмотренным .

Дальше создаем строку , с ИД юзера , и ИД строки выборки и 0 или 1 - просмотр / непросмотр ...

Но тогда получится очень много этих строк (кол-во юзеров Х на кол-во строк )

Боюсь что будет с производительностью...

Может можно как то проще сделать?

Comment: Вы всё правильно делаете.

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно, только достаточно двух полей: `user_id` и `data_id`. Единичек/нулей не нужно. Есть пара в таблице — запись просмотрена. Нет записи — читать и читать!

Проще — можно по-всякому "оптимизировать", но всему своя цена. Например, "помнить" только про последние 32 или 64 статьи на сайте, скажем: и хранить в таблице юзеров ещё три значения: два 32-битных числа (1 - читал, 0 - нет) и `id` статьи, от которой считаются эти биты. При каждом визите обновлять эти юзеровые параметры. (бредовый способ, на ходу придумал)